# Homebrew doctor warning: you have unlinked kegs in your Cellar

Tags: macos, homebrew

How do you fix this?

```
$ brew doctor
...
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built.

    imagemagick
    jasper
    libtiff
    little-cms
...
```

Comment: For future users -> this is automated script http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/125319/53973

Comment: It would be nice to understand *why* this typically happens. For software installations managed 100% through brew, how do kegs become unlinked in the first place?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Like this, for each unlinked keg:

```
brew link imagemagick
```

If you don't want to keep them, `brew cleanup` should get rid of them.

Comment: What if I have removed those 'kegs' previously? Why are they still there? I don't want to 'link' them again, I want to get rid of them.

Comment: `brew cleanup` will get rid of unused stuff

Comment: @PeterŠtibraný I also didn’t want to link to the unlinked version of something I already had via brew (no idea) so `brew cleanup` then `brew upgrade` and another  (possibly excessive tidying) `brew cleanup worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

i ran below command and the problem is gone...

"brew upgrade"

Comment: That worked for me too, good catch.

Answer (score 4):

```
brew link --overwrite imagemagick
```

repeat it for each and it will solve the issue