# Is there a quick way to relink my homebrew kegs?

Tags: homebrew

I just upgraded my MacBook Air to Mavericks.  The process appears to have removed almost all of the symlinks that `homebrew` put in `/usr/local/bin`.  As I notice things missing then I relink them via `brew unlink <keg> && brew link <keg>` (although the symlinks are gone, `homebrew` still thinks they are there so I need to `unlink` first).  This feels somewhat inefficient.

I could just loop through everything in `/usr/local/Cellar` but not *every* keg is automatically linked and I don't want to link those.  So my next guess is to list every *linked* keg and relink them (using the above).

Is there some magic command that will find all the kegs that `homebrew` *thinks* are linked so that I can relink them?

Comment: I used Migration Assistant to move "everything" from an old Mac to a new one, and I also lost all my homebrew symlinks. Annoying.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`/usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs` seems to contain a list of, well, linked kegs, so this should do the trick:

```
ls -1 /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs | while read line; do
    echo $line
    brew unlink $line
    brew link --force $line
done
```

I'd recommend ensuring you have write permissions to `/usr/local/lib` again before trying this.

Comment: Pretty sure that this just restored my homebrew into working order. Thanks!

Comment: Amazing, thank you :) 
just made a gist out of it if you don't mind, I'm pretty sure that we are not the only one who faced this problem.. 
https://goo.gl/YTPMjh

Comment: No, don't do `--force`! `brew link` should be sufficient, and some kegs really shouldn't be linked (as they can conflict with system libraries), whereas `--force` will force their linkage.

Comment: Huh. Looks like I also deleted `/usr/local/Library`.

Answer (score 72):

This bash command (taken from [there](http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/35873/Relink-all-homebrew-formulae-after-Maver/)) will unlink all installed formulas and then link them again:

```
brew list -1 | while read line; do brew unlink $line; brew link $line; done
```

I guess all formulas need to be linked, otherwise, whichever tool depends on them, won't be able to find them..

Comment: I'm not sure that all formulae do need to be linked.  Some are _keg-only_ but I don't know which, since some were installed as dependencies of others.

Comment: It seems you just get some warnings like 
"Warning: extempore is keg-only and must be linked with --force"

Comment: Here's an equivalent version using xargs: `brew list -1 | xargs -I formula sh -c "brew unlink formula && brew link formula"`

Comment: great to use. I am using 10.12.6 mac os

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the other answers to this question, you may also need to relink formula with multiple versions installed (`brew link` won't do this for you).

First, relink all the formulas you can:

```
brew list -1 | while read line; do brew unlink $line; brew link --force $line; done
```

Then run `brew doctor`, which should complain and give you two lists:

- Unlinked formulae with multiple versions
- Keg-only formulae which have been incorrectly link by the original relinking process.

For each formula with multiple versions run the following, replacing "python" with the formula name:

```
brew info python
```

This will show you, among other information, all installed versions. Choose which version you want to link (for me its 2.7.6), and use `brew switch`

```
brew switch python 2.7.6
```

You will also want to run `brew unlink` on the list (if any) of keg-only formulae that have been linked.